# ggplot2 legend title position

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the following code to create a heatmap:

```
library(ggplot2)
gamma_df <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kpclcq7o907t61/blogs_test.csv?dl=1")
p <- ggplot(data = gamma_df, aes(x=gamma2, y=gamma3, fill=predacc)) + geom_tile()
p <- p + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red",
                              limit = c(0.1,0.4), space = "Lab",
                              name="Discounts")
p <- p + theme(legend.position="right")
p
```

and my results look like this:

[image]

I've been unsuccessful in moving the legend title up a little bit so that it doesn't overlap the values.  I tried adding

```
p + guides(color=guide_colourbar(title.vjust=3))
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357815/vertical-alignment-of-legend-title-ggplot2) with various values for the **title.vjust** parameter, but without any luck. Anyone know the magic for this?

Comment: What is (or rather more pertinently how was) `p` created?

Comment: I think what Gavin mentioned is that you are missing the code to create `p`. You probably have a code something like `ggplot(gamma_df, aes(x = gamma2, y = gamma3)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = predacc))` That is something you want to add in your question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Added the missing line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution is just to add a newline at the end of the legend title:

```
library(ggplot2)
gamma_df <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kpclcq7o907t61/blogs_test.csv?dl=1")
p <- ggplot(data = gamma_df, aes(x=gamma2, y=gamma3, fill=predacc)) + geom_tile()
p <- p + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red",
                              limit = c(0.1,0.4), space = "Lab",
                              name="Discounts\n")
p <- p + theme(legend.position="right")
p
```

though you might be better off just getting rid of the `limit =`

```
gamma_df <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kpclcq7o907t61/blogs_test.csv?dl=1")
    p <- ggplot(data = gamma_df, aes(x=gamma2, y=gamma3, fill=predacc)) + geom_tile()
    p <- p + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red",
                                  space = "Lab",
                                  name="Discounts")
    p <- p + theme(legend.position="right")
    p
```

Comment: Both work fine.  I combine both of your suggestions to get the label up even higher because it looks better. Thx